# My VS code running button cannot run python program(always missing imports but they are in my anaconda folder)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, config

I have anaconda installed in my user directory.

And I can run python program normally in VS code terminal.

But if I use the run button right upper corner it always remind me imports are missing.
[image]

Didn't find a similar problem online.

I was expecting that click the run button is just equivalent as “python program.py" command

I already add anaconda to the path, but look like anaconda is different than python? Also this anaconda is installed by Pycharm if I remember right, will this have effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you choose the correct interpreter?

Use shortcuts **"Ctrl+Shift+P"** and type **"Python: Select Interpreter"** to choose the correct interpreter.

Comment: I found that in terminal it will automatically use the one under user directory but VS code has a .conda environment and recommend and use it by default

Comment: If you install the package in another interpreter and use the recommended conda environment, the package you want will not be found. You can use `conda install packageName` command to install package, or select the correct interpreter.

Comment: In general, we prefer to use virtual environment, which will not cause library confusion